# Mac Book Pro Kernel Panic On connecting DataCard

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic

I have purchased a new MacBook Pro recently. I am facing kernel panic errors every time I use my USB data card for surfing. I have reinstalled my OS but stil get kernel panic errors.

What I need to do to resolve this issue?

**Bug report shown as:**

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  12616 sec

Panics Since Last Report:          7

Anonymous UUID:                    947C5556-58AF-4B93-886D-6EDB24957F96

Wed May 25 19:55:50 2011

panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff80002d11f4): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80002c5330,
 type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000008, CR3: 0x0000000000100000, CR4: 0x0000000000040660
RAX: 0xffffff800c5eac40, RBX: 0x0000000000000008, RCX: 0x0000000001000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000008
RSP: 0xffffff805f753cf0, RBP: 0xffffff805f753cf0, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0x0000000000000008
R8:  0x00000000418df000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff80004f4e5e
R12: 0x0000000000000008, R13: 0x0000000000000246, R14: 0xffffff805f753d10, R15: 0x0000000000000010
RFL: 0x0000000000010286, RIP: 0xffffff80002c5330, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Error code: 0x0000000000000000

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff805f753990 : 0xffffff8000204d15
0xffffff805f753a90 : 0xffffff80002d11f4
0xffffff805f753be0 : 0xffffff80002e3f1a
0xffffff805f753bf0 : 0xffffff80002c5330
0xffffff805f753cf0 : 0xffffff80002503c8
0xffffff805f753d10 : 0xffffff7f80852d23
0xffffff805f753f20 : 0xffffff7f8085325c
0xffffff805f753fa0 : 0xffffff80002c84f7
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace (with dependencies):
         com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily(10.0.3)@0xffffff7f80850000->0xffffff7f80859fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
10J3210

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.7.1: Mon Jan 31 14:55:53 PST 2011; root:xnu-1504.10.48~4/RELEASE_X86_64
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 965216859070
unloaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.cd9660          1.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f80f3c000, size 0x32768) - last unloaded 555132792378
loaded kexts:
com.ZTE.driver.ModemDriverMacEx          1.0.6d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor          1.9.3d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM          100.12.31
com.apple.filesystems.autofs          2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver          1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA          2.0.2f9
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver          2.0.2f9
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC          1.53
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient          3.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl          1.0.17
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor          3.0.1d2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X          7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver          1.1.6
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin          4.6.0d12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC          1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight          170.0.43
com.apple.kext.AppleSMCLMU          1.5.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics          6.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB          6.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons          201.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard          201.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController          303.8
com.apple.BootCache          31
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib          1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient          2.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage          1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC          1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub          4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager          160.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI          4.7.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331          429.10.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet          3.0.2b8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM          1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort          2.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI          4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons          1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC          1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET          1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS          1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC          1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC          1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient          142.4.0
com.apple.security.sandbox          1
com.apple.security.quarantine          0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall          2.1.11
com.apple.iokit.CHUDUtils          364
com.apple.iokit.CHUDProf          366
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement          142.4.0
com.apple.nke.ppp          1.5 - last loaded 520102234363
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice          2.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass          2.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter          1.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter          1.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily          1.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter          1.0.5
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib          2.0.2f9
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction          17
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction          10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction          14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction          10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction          10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction          20
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController          1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI          1.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily          1.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP          2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface          74.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager          2.4.3f1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily          10.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily          1.8.3fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib          1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController          2.0.2f9
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily          2.0.2f9
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily          41.4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily          4.6.0d12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI          1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert          1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC          3.1.0d5
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport          2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily          2.2
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController          2.4.3f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController          2.4.3f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily          2.4.3f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch          207.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver          4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub          4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite          3.9.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice          2.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily          1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily          1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily          1.6.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter          402.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI          1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily          2.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient          4.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily          4.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family          320.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily          1.10
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily          2.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily          4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime          1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily          1.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily          1.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch          1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet          6
com.apple.iokit.CHUDKernLib          365
com.apple.driver.DiskImages          289
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily          1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform          1.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily          2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily          1.3.0
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B04, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.68f96
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 5.100.198.10.1)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.3f1, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9A302, 298.09 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: Hub, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: add more details about the data card. Is it USB? Which make / model? Which chipset?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the model number or chipset of that dataCard.I had took from my friend to surf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB data cards usually install their own kernel extensions (drivers), or require you to install those drivers yourself, so if you're getting panics while using it, it's probably your card's kernel extension that is buggy and causing the panic.

When your Mac kernel panics, it writes the panic details to a panic log file. If you paste the contents of your panic log file into your Question above, we can help you see which driver caused the panic (that information is usually, but not always, indicated in the panic log). The panic logs are written to different places in different versions of Mac OS X, so since you didn't say which version of Mac OS X you're running, I don't know for sure where to point you. But if your "new" MacBook Pro really is new, it'll be running Mac OS X v10.6.x (Snow Leopard), so the panic logs should be in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` .

Make sure you have the latest Mac drivers for your card. Don't trust your wireless ISP to provide the latest drivers for your card -- find who really makes the card (Novatel Wireless and Sierra Wireless are two of the biggest vendors of Mac-compatible WWAN data cards) and get the latest drivers from them. Check with your vendor to make sure the card is compatible with your version of Mac OS X. If it's a card you'd already had around, and it had been discontinued before Snow Leopard came out, it may be that they never made a Snow Leopard compatible version of the driver for that card.

**Update:**
You appear to have a ZTE brand USB data card. ZTE appears to be a manufacturer from mainland China. Their English-language website is at http://wwwen.zte.com.cn/ , but it sucks. By the way, they list their data cards under the "handset" category of their website. They do seem to have an English-language live tech support text chat widget on their website, so maybe you can try that. You'll probably have to have the exact model number and IMEI number of your data card ready to give to them.

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing that you installed the software that was on the card itself or on a DVD that came with the card. It is very common for this software to be out of date to the point of causing issues like yours. I would grab the latest version of the software from your carrier.

Verizon: vzam.net
AT&T: att.com/acm

Both of these sites include newer "drivers" that are guaranteed to work with their connection management software. Sometimes newer kernel modules / drivers that are not included with the software can cause issues as well.

I'm not sure of the others... But they're out there

Answer (score 1):

Try booting your system into 32-bit mode on the off chance that this behavior is similar to the USB tethering problem that plagues the iPhone as well.

To boot your system into 32-bit mode hold down the 3 and 2 keys when powering on your system